# Extracting polygons from embedded map

Tags: google-maps

I am wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to extract the polygons shown in the following embedded Google Map. I cannot seem to find anything using 'Inspect' or 'View Page Source'

https://sustainability.aprilasia.com/en/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the network tab in the development tools, you will see a series of requests for `.kml` endpoints. These are the polygons.

Example: https://sustainability.aprilasia.com/wp-content/uploads/kml-file/PT-Riau-Andalan-Pulp-and-Paper-Estate-Teso-West.kml